# .app file not found in Derived Data (React-native ios)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I try to build ios my react-native project, Xcode is showing that error message

`ld: file not found: /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ffcnutcqdnueacfosafqnwvmdnhh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/myapp clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

[image]

I already tried that solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27496743/9238414. it's not ok since I didn't change my target name before.

Comment: Any solution? Please help

Comment: have you tried deleting derived data completely then clean build and see if it rebuilds correctly?

Comment: Yes, I did. but not solved

Answer (score 1):

> it's frustrating. anyway, I solved the issue by creating a new scheme,
> it worked for me.